# About react native vision camera taking picture and save

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, camera, react-native-vision-camera

I am new in react native. What do I need to do if I want to have a picture on the desktop after I click on the button? Just simply want to take a picture. I have tried to do so and succeed yesterday but I can't do that now.

```
function Cam() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = React.useState(false);
  const isFocused = useIsFocused()
  const devices = useCameraDevices()
  const device = devices.back
  const camera = useRef(null)
  const takePhotoOptions = {
    qualityPrioritization: 'speed',
    flash: 'off'
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const status = await Camera.requestCameraPermission();
      setHasPermission(status === 'authorized');
    })();
  }, []);
  const takePhoto = async () => {
    try {
      //Error Handle better
      if (camera.current == null) throw new Error('Camera Ref is Null');
      console.log('Photo taking ....');
      const photo = await camera.current.takePhoto(takePhotoOptions);
      console.log(photo.path)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };




  function renderCamera() {
    if (device == null) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Loading</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
    else {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          {device != null &&
            hasPermission && (
              <>
                <Camera
                  ref={camera}
                  style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
                  device={device}
                  isActive={isFocused}
                  photo={true}
                />
                  <Text> Too much code, I delete something here </Text>
              </>
            )}
        </View>
      )
    }


  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {renderCamera()}
    </View>
  );
}


export default Cam;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JXLs.jpg)

as you can see here, the frame is not important for now.

Comment: What is the problem ? takePhoto not working ? Or you want that it save the picture on your desktop once it's taken ?

Comment: Yeah, I just don't know how to move the file to the desktop or other places. Now it's just a cache, right? and it will be deleted as soon as the simulator is turned off.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs to save the picture in a specific directory on the phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)

```
            // Create pictureDirectory if it does not exist
            await RNFS.mkdir(pictureDirectory);
            // Move picture to pictureDirectory
            const filename = R.last(data.path.split('/'))!;

            await RNFS.moveFile(data.path, `${pictureDirectory}/${filename}`);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import {Camera} from 'react-native-vision-camera';
```

instead of using `const camera = useRef(null)` use `const camera = useRef<Camera>(null)`

Comment: The OP mentions nowhere that they are using TypeScript and regarding their code, it's pretty clear that they're using plain JavaScript.